get only test coverage in sonarqube and not run the static code analysis of all the files
I am trying to get only test coverage report generated by jacoco plugin in multi-module gradle project and dont want to run static code analysis(takes lotta time).
I have tried till now:

sonar.sources = (empty), however its not working as expected.
sonar.exclusions= '**' in sonar UI, it doesnt fetch even the source code of this file and also not the coverage data.
sonar.issue.ignore.allfiles=true : not working, saying remove blank entries from onar.issue.ignore.allfiles
merged each individual modules jacoco report into a single report and gave to sonar through  sonar.coverage jacoco xmlReportPaths
plugin coverage report manually using sonar-scanner and avoid doing full static code analysis but it gives error:

Error during SonarScanner CLI execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.



There is also not enough resources available about these properties and how to do it. Please help
